# Are python list comprehensions always a good programming practice?

Tags: python, coding-style, list-comprehension

To make the question clear, I'll use a specific example.

I have a list of college courses, and each course has a few fields (all of which are strings). The user gives me a string of search terms, and I return a list of courses that match all of the search terms. This can be done in a single list comprehension or a few nested for loops.

Here's the implementation. First, the `Course` class:

```
class Course:
    def __init__(self, date, title, instructor, ID, description, instructorDescription, *args):
        self.date = date
        self.title = title
        self.instructor = instructor
        self.ID = ID
        self.description = description
        self.instructorDescription = instructorDescription
        self.misc = args
```

Every field is a string, except `misc`, which is a list of strings.

Here's the search as a single list comprehension. `courses` is the list of courses, and `query` is the string of search terms, for example "history project".

```
def searchCourses(courses, query):
    terms = query.lower().strip().split()
    return tuple(course for course in courses if all(
            term in course.date.lower() or
            term in course.title.lower() or
            term in course.instructor.lower() or
            term in course.ID.lower() or
            term in course.description.lower() or
            term in course.instructorDescription.lower() or
            any(term in item.lower() for item in course.misc)
        for term in terms))
```

You'll notice that a complex list comprehension is difficult to read.

I implemented the same logic as nested for loops, and created this alternative:

```
def searchCourses2(courses, query):
    terms = query.lower().strip().split()
    results = []
    for course in courses:
        for term in terms:
            if (term in course.date.lower() or
                term in course.title.lower() or
                term in course.instructor.lower() or
                term in course.ID.lower() or
                term in course.description.lower() or
                term in course.instructorDescription.lower()):
                break
            for item in course.misc:
                if term in item.lower():
                    break
            else:
                continue
            break
        else:
            continue
        results.append(course)
    return tuple(results)
```

That logic can be hard to follow too. I have verified that both methods return the correct results.

Both methods are nearly equivalent in speed, except in some cases. I ran some tests with timeit, and found that the former is three times faster when the user searches for multiple uncommon terms, while the latter is three times faster when the user searches for multiple common terms. Still, this is not a big enough difference to make me worry.

So my question is this: which is better? Are list comprehensions always the way to go, or should complicated statements be handled with nested for loops? Or is there a better solution altogether?

Comment: There's not a single list comprehension in the code you showed -- probably you mean *generator expressions* instead.

Comment: As a general rule: if it is hardly readable, than it is a bad idea.

Comment: `False not in <iterable>` is called `all()` in Python.

Comment: Just a minor comment from the sidelines: [`lower()` before comparisons doesn't always work](http://www.moserware.com/2008/02/does-your-code-pass-turkey-test.html).

Comment: you shouldn't be using python for this in the first place. use a relational database or something.

Comment: sorry, but this is really nasty code

Comment: @julio I know this is nasty code; it's not readable. That's why I came here for help. Suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMHO, they're good programming practice when they're clearer (or at least, no less clear) and more succinct than the alternative. In this case neither option is that clear. Personally, I'd stick the search logic in the `Course` class. This makes more sense to me as the logic is linked to the class.

```
class Course:
    def __init__(self, date, title, instructor, ID, description, instructorDescription, *args):
        self.date = date
        self.title = title
        self.instructor = instructor
        self.ID = ID
        self.description = description
        self.instructorDescription = instructorDescription
        self.misc = args

    def matches_term(self, term):
        if term in self.date.lower():
            return True
        # etc
        return False
```

And then you can use a simpler generator (or list) expression for the search:

```
def searchCourses(courses, query):
    terms = query.lower().strip().split()
    return tuple(course for course in courses
                 if all(course.matches_term(term)
                        for term in terms)
                )
```

A simple test:

```
courses = (
    Course("today", "", "", "", "", ""),
    Course("wednesday", "", "", "", "", ""),
    Course("today", "", "", "", "", ""),
    Course("sunday", "", "", "", "", ""),
)

results = searchCourses(courses, "on today or wednesday")
for course in results:
    print course.date
```

which outputs:

```
today
wednesday
today
```

Comment: Good solution, but there's a mistake. The courses have to match _all_ the terms, not just one. It's like a Google search.

Comment: @dln385 I edited the answer to require that the course matches all terms. You can see how easy it is to change operational spec details like that with a design like this, unlike your nested-for-loop-with-breaks-and-continues version.

Comment: @dln385 - my mistake, had somehow overlooked that.

Answer (score 1):

A list comprehension (or generator expression) matches up more closely with what you're trying to do, which is combinatorially generate a collection of values from some other collections of values.

Nested for loops allow you to combinatorially execute some actions. You can obviously use those actions to build up a collection and do the same thing as a list comprehension (as you  have done), but you have to add boiler plate to create the list, append to it, and return it. That intricate structure of breaks and continues at multiple loop levels is to my mind much harder to intuitively understand than the equivalent list comprehension. I still can't figure out how it works (though I suspect there are indentation errors as it appears on SO). Nested loops with break and continue are also a rich source of difficult-to-find bugs, in my experience.

In my opinion though, the true source of unreadability in both versions is the logic to test whether a course matches a query term. That operation should be factored out into a method on `Course` (as demonstrated in Blair's answer), or if you can't or don't want to alter the class, you can still define a separate function for checking whether a course matches a query term. That done, either the a for loop or a list comprehension becomes almost trivial.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that list comprehensions are not always preferable.  Sometimes a good-old `for` loop does best (I've found this to be often true when doing grammatical processing).

There is a third method, which is to use the built-in `filter` function or the `itertools.ifilter` iterator.  Like this:

```
result = ifilter(test1f, ifilter(test2f, ifilter(test3f, someiterator)))
try:
  result.next()
  return True
except StopIteration:
  return False
```

In this particular case, the number of test functions you need depends on the number of distinct search terms submitted, so I wouldn't recommend `ifilter` here unless you want to implement a way to collapse the multiple tests into a single function (which I have done for myself, but what you have is adequate so why bother).

In other simpler situations `filter` does quite nicely, and it is very efficient since it is implemented in C.  Using the iterator-based approach, you can often solve seemingly complicated problems by modifying your data stream in one or two ways (with a filter function or other things) and then passing the resulting stream to a common library function.

For example, here is a prime number sieve that greatly reduces the amount of factoring you have to do to identify prime numbers (the first wasted effort is at 49, after it has spit out 12 actual primes in a row):

```
sieve = itertools.ifilter(lambda x: x % 5 != 0,
  itertools.ifilter(lambda x: x % 3 != 0,
  itertools.ifilter(lambda x: x % 2 != 0, itertools.count(7))))
```

Comment: As an aside, since this wasn't really your question: in order to do anything like this, you're going to be storing all of the objects in memory.  Look into SQLAlchemy as a way to manage the object store and search for them using indexes.  Even if you don't have a formal database server you can use SQLite with SQLAlchemy, which will use a single file as the database.